# How to mock a method return value of a class

Tags: python, mocking

I want to mock

```
os.stat(self.tmp_file).st_size

def original_func():
     print (os.stat("test.txt").st_size==35)
```

I tried this

```
@mock.patch("os.stat")
def test(os_stat):
    stat = mock.Mock()
    stat.st_size.return_value = 35
    os_stat.return_value = stat
    original_func()
```

It does not work. The print statement should be true which it is not.

Comment: Please expand on does not work. Provide the output that indicates it is not working please. Is it not mocking and still executing the "real" method? Please explain.

Comment: @idjaw I have added the function that is using it. Please check if any additional info is needed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## You can set arbitrary attributes on Mocks.

```python
import os
import mock


def original_func():
    print(os.stat("test.txt").st_size == 35)


@mock.patch("os.stat")
def test(os_stat):
    os_stat.return_value.st_size = 35
    original_func()

test()
```

If you want an arbitrary attribute on a Mock, just make up a name and set it equal to something. If you want an arbitrary method, make up a name, and set the value of its `.return_value` to something:

```
import mock

mocky = mock.Mock()

# create an attribute `foo_attribute` and set it to a string value
mocky.foo_attribute = "hi"
print(mocky.foo_attribute)

# create a method `foo_method()` and set it to return an integer value
mocky.foo_method.return_value = 100
print(mocky.foo_method())
```

## Details

The `@mock.patch("os.stat")` decorator is mocking `os.stat()`, the constructor method of the `stat` class.

`os_stat.return_value` by default, returns a new `Mock` object instance that will be substituted for the constructor method's return value (the stat object instance) - in the scope of `def test`, which includes the nested function call to `original_func`.

That `os.stat()` object that you replace with `os_stat.return_value` object, has attributes, including `st_size`, and it is that attribute that you want to set the value of on the mock.

Assigning it the way you have done works, but note that calling `return_value` attribute on an existing mock already returns a `Mock()` by default (unless you set it to some value) so setting it to `Mock(st_size=35)` is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work

```
import os
import mock


def original_func():
    print (os.stat("test.txt").st_size == 35)


@mock.patch("os.stat")
def test(os_stat):
    os_stat.return_value = mock.Mock(st_size=35)
    original_func()

test()
```